# Populating sections in a UITableview using an array of dictionaries

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsarray, nsdictionary

I'm pretty new to iOS, but I'm getting there, but have come across a problem, and I'm pretty sure I just don't know the syntax to use.

How do I populate a UITableview with an array of dictionaries, and use a particular item in the dictionary to populate two sections?  For example, I read a plist file from a web site, that is an array of dictionaries.  In the dictionary items is an identifier called "Type".  There are two distinct "Type" variables.  One that indicates "Link" and one that indicates "Show".  What I'm trying to do is have a sectioned table with "Link" in one section and "Show" in the other section.

Here's the code I have that will read the entire array and put it into a single section, but how can I make it go into two sections?

Here's a sample of the plist.  Notice the "Type", one is "weblink" and one is "show".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>Faceboook</string>
        <key>Type</key>
        <string>weblink</string>
        <key>MapAddress</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>Address</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>Date</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>Link</key>
        <string>http://www.facebook.com/myfacebook</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>Bernardo Winery</string>
        <key>Type</key>
        <string>show</string>
        <key>MapAddress</key>
        <string>321+Lombard+St,+San+Francisco,+CA</string>
        <key>Address</key>
        <string>321 Lombard St, San Francisco, CA</string>
        <key>Date</key>
        <string>Nov 2nd and 3rd.</string>
        <key>Link</key>
        <string></string>
    </dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

Here's where it reads the plist into an NSMutableArray TableData.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

if(self)
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    
    NSString *URLString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mywebsite.com/ShowList.plist"]
                                                   encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                      error:&error];
    URLString = nil;
    
    if(error == nil)
    {
        TableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mywebsite.com/ShowList.plist"]];
    }
    else
    {
        NSString *errorString = @"No internet connection, these links may not work!";
        
        UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                     message:errorString
                                                    delegate:nil
                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                           otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [av show];

        NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ShowList" ofType: @"plist"];
        TableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
    }
}
return self;
}
```

And here is where TableData is fed into the tableView.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

//    NSLog(@"The count: %i", [TableData count]);
//    NSLog(@"Terms array %@",TableData);
//    NSLog(@"value at index %i is %@", 1, [TableData objectAtIndex:1]);

NSDictionary *tmpDic = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[TableData objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] copyItems:YES];

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
}

[[cell textLabel] setText:[tmpDic objectForKey:@"Title"]];

return cell;

}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.
Wendell

EDIT:
I implemented the following-

```
if ([[tmpDic objectForKey:@"Type"] isEqualToString:@"weblink"]) {
    if(indexPath.section==0)
    {
        [[cell textLabel] setText:[tmpDic objectForKey:@"Title"]];
    }
}

if ([[tmpDic objectForKey:@"Type"] isEqualToString:@"show"]) {
    if(indexPath.section==1)
    {
        [[cell textLabel] setText:[tmpDic objectForKey:@"Title"]];
    }
}
```

But the following is going on:

[image: Section 0]
[image: Section 1]

Comment: what you want ?? explain in sort :)

Comment: I want two sections, one for "weblink" and one for "show".  The below by Ivan almost has me where I need to be, but it is putting all rows in both sections though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would convert the data you have into an array of arrays, and then populate the table in the usual way for a sectioned table:

```
@implementation TableController {
    NSMutableArray *tableData;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ShowList" ofType: @"plist"];
    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
    NSMutableArray *showArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableArray *webArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSDictionary *dict in array) {
        if ([dict[@"Type"] isEqualToString:@"weblink"]) {
            [webArray addObject:dict];
        }else if ([dict[@"Type"] isEqualToString:@"show"]) {
            [showArray addObject:dict];
        }
    }
    tableData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:webArray,showArray nil];
    NSLog(@"%@",tableData);
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return tableData.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [tableData[section] count];
}

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section == 0) {
        return @"Web Links";
    }else if (section == 1) {
        return @"Show Locations";
    }
    return nil;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = tableData[indexPath.section][indexPath.row][@"Title"];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: That looks promising, I'll definitely give that a go.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 {
return 2;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

NSDictionary *tmpDic = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[TableData objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] copyItems:YES];

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
}
if(indexPath.section==0)
{
[[cell textLabel] setText:[tmpDic objectForKey:@"Title"]];
}else
{
[[cell textLabel] setText:[tmpDic objectForKey:@"Link"]];
}

return cell;

}
```

Comment: This maybe on the right track.  "Title" is what needs to populate the cell, with "weblink" being in section 0, and "show" being in section 1.
I tried the following but it creates two complete lists, one in each section.

    if(indexPath.section==0 && [[tmpDic objectForKey:@"Type"] isEqualToString:@"weblink"])